# Android call api route every few seconds

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

I am trying to call an api route (method) every few seconds. The method currently calls the route gets the base64 string and puts the string as an Image on my imageview. How can I constantly call this every X seconds.

Currently the method Looks like this:

```
public void getImageFromApi() {
    call = service.getStreamBase64(Utils.getApplicationname(), Utils.getStreamname());
    call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    Log.e("Tag", response.body().string() + " ");
                    String result = response.body().string(); // holds the base64 string
                    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(result, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

                    // Make the imageview visible inside the relative layout, it is GONE inside the xml ...
                    RelativeLayout drawable = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawable);
                    drawable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    drawable1.setImageBitmap(decodedByte); // put image on imageview
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                if (response.code() == 404) {
                    Toasty.error(VideoChatActivity.this, "Error Code " + response.code() + ": Cannot not access the API!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                }                 }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toasty.error(VideoChatActivity.this, "Error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I Need to call this every X seconds so that the Image updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

declare `Timer` global

```
Timer timer;
```

add this code inside `onCreate()` method

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 0, 3000); // delay in seconds
```

create a new class like this

```
private class RemindTask extends TimerTask {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    // call your method here

                   getImageFromApi();
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: So I just Need to "paste" my method to the run method?

Comment: Should I put the top three lines in my oncreate method?

Comment: @Jaan declare `Timer timer;` globally

Answer (score 1):

past this code in **onCreate();** it will call **getImageFromApi()** every 10 seconds

```
 long SECOND_IN_MILLI = 10000//10 seconds
     final Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
                                     final Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void run() {
                                             getImageFromApi();
                                            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, SECOND_IN_MILLI);
                                         }
                                     };
                                     timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, SECOND_IN_MILLI);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use android Handler for this purpose

```
handler.postDelayed(handlerTask, 1000);
```

after handlerTaskexecuted call it again

Comment: Where would I Need to call this just in the oncreate method?